# Winform: Clean way to toggle visibility of a control on TextChanged in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

I have a winform with many `TextBox` and a single message, I want the message to disappear when any of the `TextBox` are changed. Is there a clean way to achieve this without adding `TextChanged` EventHander to all `TextBox` ?

My messy way of doing it is as follows:

```
public static DialogResult ShowDialog()
{
    var inputBox = new Form { ClientSize = new Size(520, 225), FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog };
    var input1 = new TextBox { Location = new Point(25, 25)};
    var input2 = new TextBox { Location = new Point(25, 60) };

    // Many more text boxes...

    var label = new Label { Text = "Text", Location = new Point(25, 90), Visible = true };

    input1.TextChanged += new EventHandler((sender, e) => label.Visible = false);
    input2.TextChanged += new EventHandler((sender, e) => label.Visible = false);

    // Add handler for all TextBoxes...

    inputBox.Controls.Add(input1);
    inputBox.Controls.Add(input2);
    inputBox.Controls.Add(label);

    return inputBox.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write a function to create `TextBox`.

let `TextBox` initial setting and event binding code in the function.

```
private static TextBox CreateTextBox(int xPos,int yPos,Label label){

    var input1 = new TextBox { Location = new Point(xPos, yPos)};
    input1.TextChanged += new EventHandler((sender, e) => label.Visible = false);
    return input1;
}
```

You just need to call the function in `inputBox.Controls.Add` method,and pass parameters which you need.

```
public static DialogResult ShowDialog()
{
    var inputBox = new Form { ClientSize = new Size(520, 225), FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog };

    var label = new Label { Text = "Text", Location = new Point(25, 90), Visible = true };

    inputBox.Controls.Add(CreateTextBox(25, 25,label));
    inputBox.Controls.Add(CreateTextBox(25, 60,label));
    inputBox.Controls.Add(label);

    return inputBox.ShowDialog();
}
```

**NOTE**

if there are too many parameters you can try to use a class to carry those and pass.